# Injectivity, Surjectivity and zero map

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove:

1). $\lambda s $ of T are non zeroes, if T is surjective.

2). $\lambda s $ of T are non zeroes, if T is injective.

3). $\lambda s $ of T are non zeroes, if T is a zero map.

Here is thinking process: Let U be a space over $R$ and $T:\ L(U,U)$. Note that $T(u)=\lambda u$ such that $u\in U $. If eigen values ($\lambda s $) are zeros, then $Tu=0$ and $u$ is a non zero vector. Hence, T is a zero map, and it is a counter example for 3).

I got stuck for 1 and 2. I assume both are right. Here are my scratch ideas: for 1) if T is a surjective linear map, then range of T is a subspace of codomain which is U in above case. Moreover, the dim (range T) = dim (U). But, how could i link these ideas to $\lambda s$ are non zeros.

For 2). If T is injective, null T = {0} . I don't know how to continue. So please direct me and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of a linear map $T \in L(V,V)$ are all non-zero if and only if $T$ is injective.

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then a $T$ with non-zero eigenvalues would have to be surjective.  However, this is not generally the case.

The only eigenvalue of the zero map is zero, so of course the third statement, as written, is incorrect.